# Adding if statement in array item

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having trouble adding this

```
<?php echo (set_value('first_name')) ? (set_value('first_name')) : ($row->first_name); ?>
```

to the value item in the following array

```
$first_name = array(
              'name'        => 'first_name',
              'id'          => 'first_name',
              'value'       => ' ',
              'maxlength'   => '20',             
              'class'       => 'text',

            );
```

I tried using quotes and other methods but I get errors. How should I format it for array?

Comment: value, sorry. i get syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
$set_first_name = set_value('first_name');
$first_name = array(
    'name' => $set_first_name ? $set_first_name : $row->first_name,
    // etc
```

If using PHP 5.3, you can even shorten that to

```
'name' => $set_first_name ?: $row->first_name
```

Comment: oh i see! There's no need to add 'echo' in array value. thanks!